# No matching version found for @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@^7.8.3. with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli

When I am trying to create a vue project using the vue-cli it is giving me the following error message.

```
ETARGET
No matching version found for @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@^7.8.3.
In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't exist.

It was specified as a dependency of '@babel/preset-env'
```

A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/avinash/.npm/_logs/2020-01-13T23_53_01_890Z-debug.log

my node version is v12.14.1
npm version is v6.13.4

Comment: Did you try flushing NPM cache?

Comment: I tried npm cache clear

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue a while ago and this is what worked for me:

Are you perhaps using your company laptop where your npm registry is not set by default to: https://registry.npmjs.org/ ?

If yes, you may go to your .npmrc file, comment out your current registry, and set registry = https://registry.npmjs.org/

Run your vue-cli command, and then restore the .npmrc to original settings :)

Not sure if you have a similar issue but this is what worked for me.